# How to display unicode for "micron" or lower case "Mu" in a CEdit?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

How to display unicode for "micron" or lower case "Mu" in a CEdit? 
thx

```
CEdit *ed = new CEdit();
ed->Create(WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, CRect(200,100,300,120), this, 10);

CString s;
s.Format("%c", xx); //<--- how to do unicode here?
ed->SetWindowText(s);
```

---

```
I think the unicodes:
micron 0x00b5
squared 0x00b2
cubed 0x00b3
degree 0x00b0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the UNICODE project setting, this is trivial:

```
s.Format("%c", 0x3BC);
```

The CString will contain wide (UTF-16) characters which can hold most common Unicode characters in a single location; the only problem will come with Unicode code points over U+FFFF.